# How to change Oracle MAF's default springboard icon and alignment?

Tags: jdeveloper, hybrid-mobile-app, oracle-adf-mobile, oracle-maf

How can I convert given springboard toggle button from:

**This --** Right aligned menu icon, opens dropdown menu on click

[image]

[image]

**To This --** Left aligned with bars icon, directly open spring board on click.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can also do the following to achieve this.

1. Disable the default Springboard toggle button by unchecking the "Show Springboard Toggle button".
2. Drag and drop the method gotoSpringboard() method from ApplicationFeatures data control as a command link in the primary facet in all the pages.
3. Remove the text and add an springboard icon for the link or add an css class to achieve the springboard icon.

My code looks like this.

```
<amx:commandLink actionListener="#{bindings.gotoSpringboard.execute}"
                   disabled="#{!bindings.gotoSpringboard.enabled}" id="cl2" styleClass="fa fa-bars fa-2x">

  </amx:commandLink>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just modify the CSS.
You should be able to find the correct CSS selectors an then override their css attributes by using a self defined skin.
More info about MAF skinning: http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/mobile200/mobile/develop-oepe/oepe-maf-apps-create.htm#CIHCCFIG

Answer (score 0):

The Mobile Alta skin has the springboard icon on the right. But , If you use mobileFusionFx skin, the springboard is designed to be on the left by default. Either you can use the mobileFusion skin or override the CSS property of the MAF Skin by adding stylesheet. The link is already provided in the answer given by User404.