# How to display black transparent overlay on .amx page when springboard is opened?

Tags: hybrid-mobile-app, mobile-application, oracle-maf

I am new to Oracle MAF and searched a lot to display overlay with opened springboard open but nothing found. Also sample MAF apps (like WorkBetter and SlidingWindows) with Jdeveloper doesn't shows overlay with their springboard. Is there any process by which I can display overlay or it is not possible?

Comment: What do you mean by overlay? Any example?

Comment: Overlay is a semi-transparent layer which covers whole page when spring board opens.

Comment: The same answer applies like your other oracle-maf question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29492149/how-to-change-oracle-mafs-default-springboard-icon-and-alignment